# Gray screen on bootstrap without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

I use the bootstrap 3.x template but I do not use the JavaScript on it (it's one simply page) and when I remove the .js elements the screen background is grey (transperent grey)

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx//jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/smooth-scroll/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/jarallax/jarallax.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/js/script.js"></script>
```

Without this .js files my project work fine only the gray background is the problem now. 
How can I make the css or the html content to remove this gray background?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think gray background is added by the css file. Remove the css also.

Answer (score 0):

I check the code and fix the gray background.

`<div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: 0.1; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34);"></div>`

Must change the value on "style=opacity:" and of the "background-color:"

Now the source code with the white background look like so:

`<div class="mbr-overlay" style="opacity: **0.0**; background-color: rgb(**255**, **255**, **255**);"></div>`

Thanks of all!